# Possible to do TSP with mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, geojson

I'm working an a map app where I can add waypoints along specific routes.  I need to pull my waypoints out in order obviously so I can get directions from A-D in the correct order.

I've read a bit about geoJSON in mongodb but I'm curious if theres a way to query my data so that my points come out ordered by how close they are together rather than the order I've put them in.

Basically what I'm asking...Is there a way to do a "Traveling Salesman query" so that my waypoints are ordered in the smartest order?

Comment: Did I hear you correctly, you want the database to solve an NP-complete problem on each query you run? :)

Comment: Haha, well...The problem I'm having figuring out how to put the points in randomly and get them ordered correctly coming back out.  I'm open to ideas of how to achieve this.  I guess just pull the points & use google maps tps solver to order them before they are displayed?

Comment: The problem is, I have say 100 points.  I need points 10-20 but without running the entire set through a TSP solver I don't know which points are actually 10-20.  So my question should be is there a way to store my points (and add new ones) in a way that I can get them back out in an ordered fashion without having to create some sort of ordered key for my entire data set that gets updated each time I add a new point?

Comment: I don't know much about storing geo data.

Comment: You have to define first what does it mean by "get points back in ordered fashion": do you mean north to south, east to west, on the path vector, closest? Can you define what do you mean by "ordered by how close they are together"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the short answer is *no*. You're going to need to add an order key to your waypoints. This is a pretty standard pattern for any nav system with waypoints. At the very least you need to know which point is first and which is last so that you can then solve the TSP.